# javascript object properties as parameters

Tags: javascript

If in javascript object properties are passed by reference why  this doesnt work:

```
var myObj={a:1}

function myFun(x){
x=2;
}

myFun(myObj.a);

// value myObj.a is still 1
```

but on the other hand if you do this:

```
var myObj={a:1}

function myFun(x){
x.a=2;
}

myFun(myObj);

// this works myObj.a is 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Primitive values are passed by value.  Objects are passed by reference.*

Object properties are passed by based on their data type.

Here you are passing an integer - `x` represents the value 1.  Assigning `x` the value 2 does not reference the original object.

Let's say the property you pass in is an array.  And the 2nd function I call receives an array and you make changes to that array.  Then the changes will persist to the object because the object's property contains a reference to the array you modified.  You didn't technically modify the object at all... you just modified the array which is referenced in the object.  When you pass an object property to a function, it's not aware that it belongs to an object at all.

**See example, similar to yours:**

```
var myObj={a:[1]}

function fn1(x){
 x=2; //Overwrites x in this scope to the new primitive 2. 
      //This isn't reflected in myObj because x is not a 
      //reference to myObj.a  it is a reference to the array 
      //that myObj.a contains (the [1]).
}

function fn2(x){
 x.push(2);
}

fn1(myObj.a); //myObj.a is [1]
fn2(myObj.a); //myObj.a is [1,2]
```

Answer (score 2):

your first example doesn't work, because object properties are *not* passed by reference (unless the property itself also is an object).

objects, as you noticed, *are* passed by reference - thats the reason your second example works.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a base data type, it is passed by value. That is for integers, you pass the parameter by value so a copy of it is made in the local scope. Objects however are passed by reference so the function has access to the variable. You could pass it by reference, but its easier to do

```
 Obj.a=fun(Obj.a);
```